# selecting "Wowza Streaming Engine 4: Pro Edition (HVM) on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wowza, amazon-ami, marketplace

I have created a t2.medium instance by selecting "Wowza Streaming Engine 4: Pro Edition (HVM)" in the region "Oregon" from marketplace on 1 Sept around 9AM EST. I am being charged for the monthly subscription of "Wowza" but the instance is not showing up in the list. After I clicked on launch instance it says that the instance is taking so long time to install softwares in it and will be up within an hour but it is already 29 hours from now and the instance is not showing up. So could you please look into the matter and let me know where can I trace all the things?

Comment: Are you by any chance in different region? Can you check top right what region it shows?

Comment: No, actually I have checked each and every region

Comment: Did you try to restart the creation?

Comment: Have you checked if you accidentally requested a spot instance or a reserved instance? If that is the case it will appear in another section, not under "instances" menu. Moreover if you requested a spot instance it may be already terminated.

Comment: @manuel Yes I have checked it every place, I am sure that I have created it correctly

Comment: @error2007s What do you mean by restart the creation?

Comment: Restart the whole process of launching the instance again

Comment: @error2007s But they started my monthly subscription of Wowza, if the instance launch was unsuccessful then why are they charging. Also if I restart the process of launching, a new wowza subscription will be generated. Isn't it?